# jQueryUI: Vertically aligning html elements of Menu rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a jQueryUI menu with a few rows, each with the exact same type of elements. Ie:

```
  <ul id="menu1">
        <li id="row1"><span id="row1-1">Row1</span><input id="row1-2"><span id="row1-3">blah</span></li>
        <li id="row2"><span id="row2-1">Row Two</span><input id="row2-2"><span id="row2-3">blah2</span></li>
  </ul>
  <script>
  $('#menu1').menu()
  </script>
```

I would like to vertically align each same type of element, so that the text "Row1" vertically aligns with "Row Two", then `<input id="row1-2">` vertically aligns with `<input id="row2-2">`, etc.

How do I do this?

Here is the jsbin:  http://jsbin.com/IHiGEYAd/1/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way, for accessibility reasons among others, is to use label tags and give them widths:

http://jsbin.com/IHiGEYAd/3/

```
<style>
label {width: 100px; display: inline-block;}
</style>

<ul id="menu1">
    <li id="row1">
        <label for="row1-2" id="row1-1">Row1</label>
        <input id="row1-2" />
        <span id="row1-3">blah</span>
    </li>

    <li id="row2">
        <label for="row2-2" id="row2-1">Row Two</label>
        <input id="row2-2" />
        <span id="row2-3">blah2</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```